# expect for non-interactive sessions

Tags: linux, tcl, expect

I'm using docker container. I need to send bash commands to the container through expect script but i dont want the console to be opened.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set cont_name [lindex $argv 0];
spawn docker attach vont1
send "netconfd&\n"
interact
```

The problem is I need to achieve this without opening console.If I remove the interact then I'm not able to send commands to container. Is there any way to send commands to container(bash shell) without interact so that it should be executed in background.

Comment: Can you tried running it in background by appending with `&` and replace the `interact` with `expect` ?